# Vectorized Operations on two Pandas DataFrame to create a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have `orders.csv` as a dataframe called `orders_df`:

```
           Symbol Order  Shares
Date                           
2011-01-10   AAPL   BUY    100
2011-01-13   AAPL   SELL   200
2011-01-13    IBM   BUY    100
2011-01-26   GOOG   SELL   200
```

I end up sorting the data frame with `orders_df = orders_df.sort_index()`.

Then I create a `symbols` like so:

```
symbols = np.append(orders_df.loc[:, 'Symbol'].unique(), 'SPY')
```

Here comes my second DataFrame `df_prices`.

```
df_prices = get_data(symbols, orders_df.index, addSPY=False)
df_prices.loc[:, 'CASH] = 1.0
```

which prints out:

```
            AAPL IBM  GOOG XOM  SPY   CASH
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  150  100  50   400  100   1.0
2011-01-13  250  200  500  100  100   1.0
2011-01-13  250  200  500  100  100   1.0
2011-01-26  100  150  100  300  50    1.0
```

Now, I initialize a third data frame:'

```
df_trades = pd.DataFrame(0, df_prices.index, columns=list(df_prices))
```

I need to fill this data frame with the correct values using the two previous date frames. If I `BUY` `AAPL`, I want to multiply `Shares` from `orders_df` with the prices of `AAPL` times `-1`. If it were `SELL` I wouldn't multiply by `-1`. I put that value in the correct `CASH` column. For the other columns, I simply copy over the `Shares` of each stock on days they traded.

```
            AAPL IBM  GOOG XOM  SPY   CASH
Date                                                   
2011-01-10  100  0    0   0  0      -15000
2011-01-13  -200 0    0   0  0      50000
2011-01-13  0   100   0   0  0      -20000
2011-01-26  0     0  -200  0  0      20000
```

How do I achieve `df_trades` using vectorized operations?

UPDATE

What if I did:

```
df_prices = get_data(symbols, orders_df.index, addSPY=False)
df_prices.loc[:, 'CASH] = 1.0
```

which prints out

```
          AAPL     IBM    GOOG    XOM     SPY  CASH
2011-01-10  340.99  143.41  614.21  72.02  123.19   1.0
2011-01-11  340.18  143.06  616.01  72.56  123.63   1.0
2011-01-12  342.95  144.82  616.87  73.41  124.74   1.0
2011-01-13  344.20  144.55  616.69  73.54  124.54   1.0
2011-01-14  346.99  145.70  624.18  74.62  125.44   1.0
2011-01-18  339.19  146.33  639.63  75.45  125.65   1.0
2011-01-19  337.39  151.22  631.75  75.00  124.42   1.0
```

How would I produce the `df_trades` then?

The example values aren't valid anymore fyi.

Comment: can you show your non vectorized code?

Comment: I haven't built `df_trades` yet. Those are just what the value are supposed to be.

Comment: I don't really understand the logic of your df_trades. Shouldn't the first CASH value be -15000 if i buy 100 APPL for a price of 150? Do you want df_trades to resemble you inventory or the change in inventory? If there are several prices for one day in the price_df which value should be used for each transaction?

Comment: I want change in inventory, so I think you're right. I don't believe there will be several prices in one day for a single stock on a single day in prices_df.

Comment: `df_prices`: why do you have two 2011-01-13 dates with different prices?

Comment: That was another mistake. They should be the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vectorized Solution**

```
j = np.array([df_trades.columns.get_loc(c) for c in orders_df.Symbol])
i = np.arange(len(df_trades))
o = np.where(orders_df.Order.values == 'BUY', -1, 1)
v = orders_df.Shares.values * o
t = df_trades.values
t[i, j] = v

df_trades.loc[:, 'CASH'] = \
    df_trades.drop('CASH', 1, errors='ignore').mul(prices_df).sum(1)
df_trades

            AAPL  IBM  GOOG  XOM  SPY     CASH
Date                                          
2011-01-10  -100    0     0    0    0 -15000.0
2011-01-13   200    0     0    0    0  50000.0
2011-01-13     0 -100     0    0    0 -30000.0
2011-01-26     0    0   200    0    0  20000.0
```

Comment: Nice answer, could `orders_df[['Symbol', 'Shares']].pivot(columns='Symbol', values='Shares').fillna(0).astype(int)` also work here?

Comment: The problem is that OP has data with a non-unique index.  In order to achieve the desired output, I needed to trust that the indices are aligned and ignore them.  IMO, it would be better to distinguish between the two `2011-01-13` index values with a timestamp, or some enumeration.  But I figured that I'd just answer the OP's question instead of re-architecting his scenario.  I suspect the pivot would fail due to the non-uniqueness... not your code... that's fine code... I mean fail in the sense as to not achieve OP's output.

Comment: @pi I follow you.  I was actually surprised there's no param in `pivot` or `pivot_table` that maintains the index rather than consolidating to a uniquely-valued one.

Comment: Actually there is an issue with `j`. `j.shape` returns `17` when there are actually `6` columns in `t`. How would you resolve this?

Comment: I don't understand `t[i , j]` because `i` and `j` are lists not integers.